# CSS menu image in WordPress

Tags: css, menu

I´m coding a CSS menu for Wordpress and I have this stupid problem:

I give the first `ul` a background image and that same image shows also on every sub menus, which I don´t want.

How can I tell the first `ul` that the background image is only for that `ul`? And not for the following sub menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the selector for ul where you want the image to appear. 
You CSS code should look something like

```
.nav > ul {
background: url("........
}
```

Assuming nav is the class attached to immediate parent of desired ul.

Answer (score 0):

**Two ways**

Set the background of your sub-menus to the background-color your site has.

or

Show us your code, because I think you used something like

```
ul { background: url(...) }
```

which applies for all `<ul>`-elements, even your sub lists.